# Sharepoint list disappear

Tags: list, web-part, error, sharepoint-addin

Today all lists of my sharepoint all site are suddenly disappeared.I do not know what happened in the end. Now all the list can not display it.When I click on the list will be displayed some error.
like this:

[image]

This result is not only this list displayed. All of site, All of list ,All displayed on this page. Even in the event of this thing, and then create a new list will be displayed on this page.

When I go to the root directory of sharepoint site to find the file, I found that even folders are GONE!!!!!!!!!!!! They were abducted by aliens.

I suspect this is I broke it. I made a webpart deployed on the site. The function of the webpart is extract the current list of information and saved to a file. After deployment, it shows not find the file path. The path is web site root directory \lists\wordtest\test\just for test.docx
Then I found out there is no root directory folder called list. So I follow the prompts to create a new folder named list and the subfolder.

AFTER THAT ALL LISTS ARE GONE!!!!!!! I know it still exists, but I do not see it. I can see it in the sharepoint designer and I can edit all of the pages inside. But the result is always wrong to get on the page.

I need your help very much. I will be very grateful to you.

Comment: Please add errors from ULS logs for more investigations. C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS

Comment: @AndreyUngur The log said the same message. Can not find the page and the resource.

Answer (score 1):

Without the ULS logs it's difficult to be precise but it sounds like the default master page may be broken.

If you have modified the default v4.master or nightday.master (if a publishing site) then you'll need to either revert back to the site definition get a copy from another site collection and overwrite your broken site collection's version.  You can do this in SharePoint designer.

If you haven't changed the content of the master page, then changing the default and custom to the v4.master may bring back your lists. You can also do this in SharePoint designer - Master Pages, select v4.master and click both default and custom button on the ribbon.

Comment: I never change the master page, even don't know where it is. Just saw it in SharePoint designer every time. I check it before , nothing change of it. Maybe there is something result in it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Site Recycle Bin and restore everything under \lists\ (including that folder).